# 10 Gb JVM Heap Memory full but only 1Gb Field data cache

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a ES 1.6 cluster with 4 nodes used to store mostly logging data (~500 documents a second).

ES is configured with 10G of Heap but after numerous OutOfMemoryExceptions and stop-the-world GCs we limited the Field data cache to 10%.

My question is, why are all nodes' JVM constantly using ~9Gb Heap when field data (which i understand to be one of the primary users of Heap) is limited to 1Gb.

Some graphs:
[image: jvm heap]
[image: cache sizes]

It's worth pointing out our filter cache size is much smaller (~200Mb) and yes the aggressively limited Field data cache size does cause a lot of Field data cache evictions.

What else is using so much heap?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any useful mappings to share and also maybe some sample queries that illustrate how you're hitting your cluster?

Comment: There are lots of things that can affect heap in ES. Can you provide more details? Especially stats per node from ES itself? ES will use heap not only for fileddata. And there is also Lucene - it can also use heap extensively.